# error when calling promise function within another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code that gives an error when I try to load it to my interactive node console using the command `.load myFile.js`

```
var Q=require('q');
var promise1 = function(x){
    var def = Q.defer();
    setTimeout(function(){
        def.resolve(x*5);
    },3000);
    return def.promise;
};

var process = function(val){
    promise1(val);
};
```

Here is my error:

```
Failed to load:myFile.js

_stream_writable.js:258
      process.nextTick(function() {
              ^
TypeError: Object function (val){
promise1(val);
} has no method 'nextTick'
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:258:15)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:97:5)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:651:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:613:40)
    at REPLServer.repl.defineCommand.action (repl.js:858:27)
    at REPLServer.parseREPLKeyword (repl.js:670:16)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:219:16)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`process` is a built-in Node.js global.

By making your own `process` variable in the REPL (which does not have its own scope), you broke everything.

Comment: This is one of the more effective ways to break everything that does not require deliberate malice (such as `delete Array.prototype.forEach` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function() { return 0; };`)